# Pygame window appears, but no image shows up

Tags: python, pygame

> I am following a book tutorial that originally told me to use a .bmp for a picture because that was the default type of image file that pygame identifies and can open, but it didn't work. I got a pygame.error saying that it could not open it, and I suspect because I'm using macOS. So I tried using a .png, but that isn't working either.

import pygame

class Ship():

```
def __init__(self, screen):
    """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
    self.screen = screen

    # Load the ship image and get its rect.
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.png')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
    self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
    self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

def blitme(self):
    """Draw the ship at its current location."""
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: if your on windows change ('images/ship.png') to ('.\images\ship.png')

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a main loop that updates the display? (asking since I can't see it in your code)
like this:

```
done=False
while done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done=True
    pygame.display.flip() #Update the screen
```

For the image to show you need to update the window, which is exactly what `pygame.display.flip()` does.